# why callback in Dom Event can get a argument object e automatically?

Tags: javascript

When I init a callback for a DOM Event ,it will automatically get a argument e ,it is a Event Object,how can js do this? why does it can get a parameter e  which type is a Object ?

```
liDom.onclick=function (e){console.log(e)}
```

Why callback knows e is a Event Object?

Comment: When theres an event, the JS engine does *liDOM.onclick(new Event(...));* ...

Comment: ...theres no magic going on, sorry :/

Comment: The code that calls the onclick function passes the event object to it. That's how the API is defined.

Comment: Because it's part of the API...

Comment: @Jonasw when I use the map method in a array instance ,its callback will get arguments  item and index ,how the callback function get it? I am sort of confused

Comment: @user7980590 its called?? with these arguments?? callback(this[i],i); ...

Comment: it's the javascript implementation - the native code. Check javascript documentation for map function - it is defined that way. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map

Comment: @Jonasw sorry I'm not a native speaker I can not express my ideas more clearly

Comment: @user7980590 wich language would be better?

Comment: @Jonasw a very difficult language in the world,I am afraid you can't understand it

Comment: @user7980590 ive already explained it to you in my best english ( im not a native speaker too), i think no one than you can help you with understanding...

Comment: @Jonasw I see!because the callback function is called  in map method in this way in its context :callback(this[i],I),so when I define a callback its argument will be a alias of this[i],I'm a little stupid

Comment: @user7980590 wohoooo. Lets close this question ( as itll never be answered)

Comment: @Jonasw I m  a new to stackoverflow ,I don't know how to do this, in fact many things about this website I can't use well,some functions I don't know what it is planned for